# Comparing Individual and Group Scores Before and After an Experiment: Methodological Considerations

Tags: t-test, pre-post-comparison

I want to compare scores before and after an experiment.
However, the samples before the experiment consist of individual scores, while the samples after the experiment are composed of groups of two individuals, resulting in group scores.

In other words, there are twice as many samples before the experiment as there are after.

For example:

```
Individual score (Pre) --- Group Score (Post)

PA1 30                     PA1 - PA2 40
PA2 25

PA3 50                     PA3 - PA4 30
PA4 10
```

I initially planned to simply double the group scores and conduct a paired t-test.

For instance, comparing the pre-scores of PA1 (30) to (40) and also comparing the pre-scores of PA2 (25) to (40). I'm wondering if this approach is appropriate, or if I should use a different method?"

Comment: Why this strange approach? How where the post group scores obtained? Are they means of individual scores? Are the groups of people pre and post the same? Or are the post group scores  obtained some other way?